# Segfault when attempting to nullify a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

So right now I'm trying to implement a deltaclock, and the first step that I'm trying is to first make a priority queue which uses a double-linked list (I will do the other deltaclock stuff later).  The first element to be popped from the priority queue is the one that is at the root of the linked list (or the deltaClock struct).

I push a few elements onto the queue in my test, and after a few pop operations, there is one case in which it segfaults when it's popping from a nearly empty list.

When I comment out the line in the pop method where I say "clock->root->previous = 0;", the program in the main method does not segfault when I pop off elements.  However, the pointer to the previous node needs to be gotten rid of since the previous node will not exist anymore.

How can I make it so that the new root's previous pointer will be null when I perform the pop operation?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct deltaNode{
    int tics;                  // source
    struct deltaNode* next;
    struct deltaNode* previous;
};

struct deltaClock{
    struct deltaNode* root;
    struct deltaNode* tail;
    int size;
};

void initDeltaClock(struct deltaClock **clock){
    (*clock) = malloc(sizeof(struct deltaClock));
    (*clock)->size = 0;
}

void push(struct deltaClock* clock, int numberOfTics){
if(clock->root == 0){
    // root is empty, initialize it.
    clock->root = malloc(sizeof(struct deltaNode));
    clock->root->tics = numberOfTics;
    clock->tail = clock->root;
} 
else {
    struct deltaNode* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct deltaNode));
    newNode->tics = numberOfTics;
    struct deltaNode* temp = clock->root;

    if(newNode->tics < temp->tics){
        clock->root->previous = newNode;
        newNode->next = clock->root;
        clock->root = newNode;
    } else {
        while(newNode->tics > temp->tics){
            if(temp->next == 0){
                break;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        if(temp->next == 0 && newNode->tics > temp->tics){
            clock->tail->next = newNode;
            newNode->previous = clock->tail;
            clock->tail = newNode;
        }
        else{
            temp->previous->next = newNode;
            newNode->previous = temp->previous;
            newNode->next = temp;
            temp->previous = newNode;
        }

    }

}
clock->size++;
}

int pop(struct deltaClock* clock){
    struct deltaNode* temp = clock->root;
       if(temp == 0){
        return -1;
    }
    int result = temp->tics;
    clock->root = clock->root->next;
    clock->root->previous = 0;
    free(temp);
    clock->size--;
    return result;
}

void printClock(struct deltaClock* clock){
    struct deltaNode* iterator;
    iterator = clock->root;
    while(iterator != 0){
            printf("\n%d",iterator->tics);
            iterator = iterator->next;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("\nHello world.");
    struct deltaClock* clock;
    initDeltaClock(&clock);
    push(clock, 3);
    push(clock, 2);
    push(clock, 7);
    push(clock, 33);
    push(clock, 221);
    push(clock, 5);
    printClock(clock);
    printf("\npopping %d",pop(clock));
    printf("\npopping %d",pop(clock));
    printf("\npopping %d",pop(clock));
    printf("\npopping %d",pop(clock));
    printf("\npopping %d",pop(clock));
    printf("\npopping %d",pop(clock));
    printf("\npopping %d",pop(clock));
    printf("\npopping %d",pop(clock));
    printf("\npopping %d",pop(clock));
    printf("\npopping %d",pop(clock));
    printf("\npopping %d",pop(clock));
    printf("\npopping %d",pop(clock));
    push(clock, 25);
    printf("\npopping %d",pop(clock));
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: +1 for including an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — thank you.  And it reproduces a problem for me, crashing after 'popping 7'.

Comment: In `pop` you don't check if `clock->root` isn't `NULL` after you assign it `clock->root->next`. Also, for pointers it's custom to use `NULL` instead of `0`.

Comment: In C++, it is more usual to use 0; I use 0 most of the time in C, though if some code is using NULL, I continue to use NULL (consistency is more important than how you spell the null pointer).

Comment: In general, and _especially_ when trying to debug something, make sure that your `printf()` messages _end_ with a newline.  Otherwise, the output doesn't appear in a timely manner.  When the printing is changed to add the newline after the 'popping' messages, instead of crashing after it pops 7, it crashes after it (apparently successfully) pops 33, which means there's only 221 left.  So, the problem occurs when you pop the last item off the stack.  However, the funny method of printing disguises that.

Comment: Building on Kninnug's observation, you also leave `clock->root->next` and `clock->root-previous` uninitialized and therefore indeterminate in your push function. Any usage of those by-value or by-dereference is **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, this code runs reasonably sanely:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct deltaNode
{
    int tics;                  // source
    struct deltaNode *next;
    struct deltaNode *previous;
};

struct deltaClock
{
    struct deltaNode *root;
    struct deltaNode *tail;
    int size;
};

void initDeltaClock(struct deltaClock * *clock);

void initDeltaClock(struct deltaClock * *clock)
{
    (*clock) = malloc(sizeof(struct deltaClock));
    (*clock)->size = 0;
}

void push(struct deltaClock *clock, int numberOfTics);

void push(struct deltaClock *clock, int numberOfTics)
{
    if (clock->root == 0)
    {
        // root is empty, initialize it.
        clock->root = malloc(sizeof(struct deltaNode));
        clock->root->tics = numberOfTics;
        clock->tail = clock->root;
    }
    else
    {
        struct deltaNode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct deltaNode));
        newNode->tics = numberOfTics;
        struct deltaNode *temp = clock->root;

        if (newNode->tics < temp->tics)
        {
            clock->root->previous = newNode;
            newNode->next = clock->root;
            clock->root = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            while (newNode->tics > temp->tics)
            {
                if (temp->next == 0)
                    break;
                temp = temp->next;
            }

            if (temp->next == 0 && newNode->tics > temp->tics)
            {
                clock->tail->next = newNode;
                newNode->previous = clock->tail;
                clock->tail = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                temp->previous->next = newNode;
                newNode->previous = temp->previous;
                newNode->next = temp;
                temp->previous = newNode;
            }
        }
    }
    clock->size++;
}

int pop(struct deltaClock *clock);

int pop(struct deltaClock *clock)
{
    struct deltaNode *temp = clock->root;
    if (temp == 0)
        return -1;
    int result = temp->tics;
    clock->root = clock->root->next;
    if (clock->root != 0)
        clock->root->previous = 0;
    free(temp);
    clock->size--;
    return result;
}

void printClock(struct deltaClock *clock);

void printClock(struct deltaClock *clock)
{
    struct deltaNode *iterator;
    iterator = clock->root;
    while (iterator != 0)
    {
        printf(" %d", iterator->tics);
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello world.\n");
    struct deltaClock *clock;
    initDeltaClock(&clock);
    push(clock, 3);
    push(clock, 2);
    push(clock, 7);
    push(clock, 33);
    push(clock, 221);
    push(clock, 5);
    printClock(clock);
    printf("popping %d\n", pop(clock));
    printf("popping %d\n", pop(clock));
    printf("popping %d\n", pop(clock));
    printf("popping %d\n", pop(clock));
    printf("popping %d\n", pop(clock));
    printf("popping %d\n", pop(clock));
    printf("popping %d\n", pop(clock));
    printf("popping %d\n", pop(clock));
    printf("popping %d\n", pop(clock));
    printf("popping %d\n", pop(clock));
    printf("popping %d\n", pop(clock));
    printf("popping %d\n", pop(clock));
    push(clock, 25);
    printf("popping %d\n", pop(clock));
    printf("\n");
}
```

It produces:

```
Hello world.
 2 3 5 7 33 221
popping 2
popping 3
popping 5
popping 7
popping 33
popping 221
popping -1
popping -1
popping -1
popping -1
popping -1
popping -1
popping 25
```

The primary change is not setting `clock->root->previous = 0;` unless `clock->root` is not null.

Secondary changes are adding newlines to the end of the print statements, and removing them from the beginning.  And the list is printed horizontally, multiple numbers per line, rather than one number per line.

The code shown compiles cleanly using:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition pl.c -o pl
```

The function declarations are needed to compile cleanly with those options; they're a good idea in general.  The alternative is to make the functions all static, which also works for single-file programs.  The only changes needed to make the code compile cleanly were adding the function prototypes and replacing `main(int argc, char **argv)` with `main(void)` — well done, that's unusually good.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other advice given, when dealing with pointers, it's a good idea to always initialize them to NULL or to their final value, don't leave them dangling.

For example, in `initDeltaClock`, `(*clock)->root` and `(*clock)->tail` are not initialized.  This means that in the first `push` call, even the check for `if (clock->root == 0)` will be invalid, since `clock->root` has not been initialized to 0.

Here's a suggested improvement:

```
void initDeltaClock(struct deltaClock **clock){
    (*clock) = calloc(sizeof(struct deltaClock));  /* <-- zero out entire contents after alloc */
}
```

The same applies to structs which are `malloc`'ed in `push`, you could use `calloc` instead of `malloc` to ensure that the blocks returned are cleared to zero, or you should set the struct's pointers to zero explicitly.

Also, if this is more than a toy project, **always** check the return value of allocation functions to check for out of memory errors.